# How are these two equivalent?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\frac{\ln(e^x+x)}{x}=\frac{e^x+1}{e^x+x}$$

I see that they did something to get rid of the natural log. I couldn't find any properties that would allow me to do this. I also think that they raised both the numerator and denominator by $e$. I have tried it and I did not get the same result. Does anyone know how the solution manual got this? I am supposed to use L'Hopital's rule to find the limit as x approaches $0$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: They are not equivalent expressions. However, their limits as $x$ approaches $0$ are equivalent by L'Hospital's rule. Differentiate the numerator and denominator to see this.

Comment: Those two aren't equal; that's actually the application of L'Hopital's rule (differentiating the numerator and denominator).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{\ln(e^x+x)}{x} \; \neq \;\;\frac{e^x+1}{e^x+x}$$

It's the application of l'Hospital's rule to the left hand side: take the derivative of the LHS's numerator and of the denominator.

$$\large \frac{e^x+1}{e^x+x}=\frac{\frac{e^x+1}{e^x+x}}{1} = \frac{\frac d{dx}\left({\ln(e^x+x)}\right)}{\frac d{dx}(x)}$$

So $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(e^x+x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x+1}{e^x+x}$$

Comment: I have applied L'Hopital's rule but I did not get $e^x+1$ in the numerator, I only got $e^x$. Did I forget to do something?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}(e^{x} + x) = e^{x} + 1$

Comment: Oops, I see my mistake. I forgot to apply chain rule since $x$ can be differentiated.

Comment: Exactly...chain rule will get you what you need.

Comment: @amWhy: $cos(0)$ :-)

Answer (score 3):

The equation that you wrote is false. The correct statement is an application of l’Hospital’s rule:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(e^x+x)}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x+1}{e^x+x}\;.$$

Since both $\ln(e^x+x)$ and $x$ approach $0$ as $x\to 0$, you can apply l’Hospital’s rule to evaluate the limit. To do this you must differentiate the numerator and the denominator separately.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(e^x+x)=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(e^x+x)}{e^x+x}=\frac{e^x+1}{e^x+x}\;,$$

and of course $\frac{dx}{dx}=1$, so

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(e^x+x)}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{e^x+1}{e^x+x}}1=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x+1}{e^x+x}\;.$$

It is **not** true without the limits.